# Python. проблема с for(), выводит повторяющиеся значения

Tags: python, for

```
   import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

product = input("Введите текст для поиска на Avito.ru: ")

url = "https://www.avito.ru/moskva?q=" + product
request = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")

all_links = bs.find_all("a", class_="iva-item-title-py3i_") # Поиск класса с сылкой на товар
wallet = bs.find_all("span", class_="price-text-_YGDY")     # Поиск класса с ценой на товар
opisan = bs.find_all("div", class_="date-text-KmWDf")       # Поиск класса со временем публикации

for link, wal, link  in zip(all_links, wallet, opisan):

    print("https://www.avito.ru" + link["href"], link["title"], wal.text, op.text)
            # link["href"] - ссылка на товар
            # link["title"] - вывод названия
            # z - нумирация строк
            # wal.text - вывод цены
            # op.text - вывод времени от публикации
```

Comment: Я уже понял, что это из-за повторяющихся for(), но не могу понять как вывести по другому. Также если кто-то сможет помочь с file.write (у меня выводит "None" в текстовый документ).

Comment: Клейте списки `all_links`, `wallet`, `opisan` через функцию `zip()` и идите по нему одним циклом.

Comment: Поменял на цикл zip(), теперь пишет:" return self.attrs[key] KeyError: 'href'".

Answer (score 0):

```
for link, wal, op  in zip(all_links, wallet, opisan):

    print("https://www.avito.ru" + link["href"], link["title"], wal.text, op.text)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).